# How to return whole document from aggregation

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am currently using MonGODB v2.6.4 for no other reason than Robomongo doesn't yet support MongoDB v3.0.

Using the following example documents, which is not how I would structure them if it were not a cut down example of what I am trying to do.

```
db.visitors.insert({
    "visits" : [{"building" : "building01", "lastVisit" : new ISODate("2015-02-01 17:05:00")},
                {"building" : "building02", "lastVisit" : new ISODate("2015-02-04 04:25:00")},
                {"building" : "building03", "lastVisit" : new ISODate("2015-02-07 15:45:00")},
                {"building" : "building04", "lastVisit" : new ISODate("2015-02-10 15:45:00")}
               ],

 "firstName" : "John",
 "lastName" : "Smith",
 "gender" : "male",
 "accountNumber" : "123456789",
 });

db.visitors.insert({
    "visits" : [{"building" : "building01", "lastVisit" : new ISODate("2015-02-02 17:05:00")},
                {"building" : "building02", "lastVisit" : new ISODate("2015-02-05 04:25:00")},
                {"building" : "building03", "lastVisit" : new ISODate("2015-02-08 15:45:00")},
                {"building" : "building04", "lastVisit" : new ISODate("2015-02-11 15:45:00")}
               ],

 "firstName" : "Jane",
 "lastName" : "Smith",
 "gender" : "female",
 "accountNumber" : "987654321",
 });

db.visitors.insert({
    "visits" : [{"building" : "building01", "lastVisit" : new ISODate("2015-02-03 17:05:00")},
                {"building" : "building02", "lastVisit" : new ISODate("2015-02-06 04:25:00")},
                {"building" : "building03", "lastVisit" : new ISODate("2015-02-09 15:45:00")},
                {"building" : "building04", "lastVisit" : new ISODate("2015-02-12 15:45:00")}
               ],

 "firstName" : "James",
 "lastName" : "Smith",
 "gender" : "male",
 "accountNumber" : "123056780",
 });
```

I want to find the last visitor to a particular building and  need the whole document for that visitor returning.

I have worked out this aggregation query that almost does what I want:

```
db.visitors.aggregate([
  {$match: {"visits.building": "building02"}},
  {$unwind: "$visits"},
  {$project: {"visitorId": "$_id", "building": "$visits.building", "lastVisit": "$visits.lastVisit"}},
  {$sort: {"lastVisit": 1}},
  {$group: {"_id": "$building", "visitorId": {$last: "$visitorId"}, "lastVisit": {$last: "$lastVisit"}}},
  {$match: {"_id": "building02"}},
  {$limit: 1}
])
```

and returns this structure:

```
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : "building02",
            "visitorId" : ObjectId("55098990ca5b44f2858f4cb5"),
            "lastVisit" : ISODate("2015-02-12T15:45:00.000000:00")
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1.0000000000000000
}
```

How can I modify the aggregate query to return the whole of the visitor document not just the visitorId?  I have tried (and failed using `$$ROOT` and `$$CURRENT`).

If returning the whole document is not possible how do I then do a find on the returned result structure so that I can retrieve it by id? I have been trying variations on this theme:

```
var result = db.visitors.aggregate([
  {$match: {"visits.building": "building02"}},
  {$unwind: "$visits"},
  {$project: {"visitorId": "$_id", "building": "$visits.building",  "lastVisit": "$visits.lastVisit"}},
  {$sort: {"lastVisit": 1}},
  {$group: {"_id": "$building", "visitorId": {$last: "$visitorId"}, "lastVisit": {$last: "$lastVisit"}}},
  {$match: {"_id": "building02"}},
  {$limit: 1}
])

db.individuals.find({_id: {$eq: {result.visitorId: {$slice: [0, 1]}}}})
```

I would prefer to do the whole thing in one query but if I can't, then I can't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need $group, so there's no need to worry about `$$ROOT` or struggling to get back all of the fields. You'll get back (a copy) of the original document with just the most recent visit left in the `visits` array.

```
> db.visitors.aggregate([ 
    { "$match" : { "visits.building" : "building02" } },
    { "$unwind" : "$visits" }, 
    { "$match" : { "visits.building" : "building02" } },
    { "$sort" : { "visits.lastVisit" : -1 } }, { "$limit" : 1 }
])
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5509e963b8b4702f49ffcee6"),
    "visits" : {
        "building" : "building02",
        "lastVisit" : ISODate("2015-02-06T04:25:00Z")
    },
    "firstName" : "James",
    "lastName" : "Smith",
    "gender" : "male",
    "accountNumber" : "123056780"
}
```

If you want the entire `visits` array, then I'd just project the `_id` through the pipeline and do a find with it after the pipeline returns, to get the whole document.

Comment: So the $group in my query was unnecessary and the $project was actually hiding the result I wanted. DOH! Your changes give me exactly what I want, thanks.